# Pass Object Array into Request Body

Tags: c#, rest, api

I have an object defined as follows.

```
public class ILT
{
    public items items;
    public options options;
}

public class items
{
    public string course_code { get; set; }
    public string session_code { get; set; }
    public string date_name { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string time_start { get; set; }
    public string time_end { get; set; }
    public string location_name { get; set; }
    public string location_address { get; set; }
    public string location_country { get; set; }

    public items() { }

    public items(string course_code, string session_code, string date_name, 
    string date, string time_start, string time_end, string location_name, 
    string location_address, string location_country)
        {
            this.course_code = course_code;
            this.session_code = session_code;
            this.date_name = date_name;
            this.date = date;
            this.time_start = time_start;
            this.time_end = time_end;
            this.location_name = location_name;
            this.location_address = location_address;
            this.location_country = location_country;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to pass the object into a RestfulAPI request body.  The "items" attribute is supposed to be an array of objects.

The JSon should be formatted as follows:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "course_id": 6,
      "session_code": "my session code",
      "session_name": "my session name",
      "session_maximum_enrollments": 20,
      "session_last_subscription_date": "2018-10-27",
      "completion_type": "Evaluation",
      "score_base": 100,
      "date_name": "my date name",
      "date": "2018-10-28",
      "timezone": "America/New_York",
      "time_start": "08:00:00",
      "time_end": "12:00:00",
      "location_name": "my location name",
      "location_address": "10850 W. Park Place Suite 600, Milwaukee, WI 53225",
      "location_country": "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA"
    }
  ],
  "options": {
    "update_session_info": true
  }
}
```

I'm having difficulty getting the items into an array.  I'm trying to initialize the object into the request body as follows:

```
public bool CreateILT()
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Token))
                Token = request.GetToken();

            ILT classroom = new ILT
            {
                items = new items[0]
                (   
                    course_code = "APS_CLASSROOM",
                    session_code = "APS_CLASSROOM",
                    date_name = "August 27, 2018",
                    date = "2018-10-27",
                    time_start = "08:00:00",
                    time_end = "17:00:00",
                    location_name = "Crisis Prevention Institute",
                    location_address = "10850 W. Park Place Suite 600, Milwaukee, WI 53225",
                    location_country = "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA"
                ),
                options = new options
                {
                    update_session_info = true
                }

            };

            dynamic response = request.Request_POST("/learn/v1/ilt/session/batch", Token, classroom);
            if (response.data.success.ToString() == "True")
                success = true;

            return success;
        }
```

Am I able to initialize an object array like this?  I'm getting errors of various types when tweaking around.  The above code errors out on each of the object's member's saying it does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

Your class variable decleration is wrong. It stores object, not array/list of objects. And I could not see your `options` class. Do you have it right?

It should be declared as follows:

```
public class ILT
{
    public List<items> items;
    public options options;
}
```

And you should initialize it as follows:

```
ILT classroom = new ILT
{
    items = new List<items> {
        new item(   
            course_code = "APS_CLASSROOM",
            session_code = "APS_CLASSROOM",
            date_name = "August 27, 2018",
            date = "2018-10-27",
            time_start = "08:00:00",
            time_end = "17:00:00",
            location_name = "Crisis Prevention Institute",
            location_address = "10850 W. Park Place Suite 600, Milwaukee, WI 53225",
            location_country = "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA")
    },
    options = new options
    {
        update_session_info = true
    }
};
```

Comment: The object class is just a single member class that isn't an array, so that one was okay.  It just passes a single bool.

Even when I do the above, it says that each of the member isn't found in the context.

Comment: I was able to fix it by replacing the = with :.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helps